# Does ES6 help grow the Ecmascript standard library?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript, es6

With all the noise about EC6, one thing that I realized I haven't heard about is expanding Javascript's standard library. Javascript has a fairly sparse standard library. You need a 3rd party library to do many basic things like date manipulation.

I'd rather have more built into the browser via a standard library then have to download Javascript to do basic things.

Is this a focus of the standards body? Is it contingent on ES6 modules? Is it even correct to discuss an "Ecmascript standard library" (does the standard specify a std lib like say C++'s spec does) or is it something specific to the Javascript implementation of the Ecmascript standard?

Answer (score 4):

It’s certainly something that’s considered in every standard, but I would say that yes, a more comprehensive standard library is a focus of ES6; comparing it to the changes in every other revision of JavaScript (which have, for the most part, added functions to existing types), you’ll notice that it’s… a lot more. No, the changes are not contingent on modules.

Truly new in ES6 (i.e. not a renamed or improved version of something else):

- `Array.from`, `Array#fill`, `Array#find`, `Array#findIndex`
- `Map`, `WeakMap`, and `Set` types
- `Number.isInteger`
- `String.fromCodePoint`, `String#codePointAt`, `String#startsWith`, `String#endsWith`, `String#contains`, `String#repeat`, `String#normalize` – lots to do with Unicode, not just UTF-16
- `Object.is`, `Object.setPrototypeOf`, `Object.assign`, `Object.observe`
- `Math.imul`, `Math.clz32`, `Math.fround` – performance things
- `Promise` – hugely important for asynchronous code

All in all, several things that would be very nice to have in the JavaScript standard library.

… I would rather have had more of this than modules and other breaking changes.

Comment: thats all good stuff, I was kind of hoping to start seeing more build out of a standard tools like python's std lib. I'm just imagining how much bandwidth is used to transfer stuff that should just be there